# Is it possible to bind each TextField created using ForEach method to its own variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to bind each TextField created using ForEach method to its own variable in SwiftUI?

```
    @State var textField1 = ""
    @State var textField2 = ""
    @State var textField3 = ""
    @State var textField4 = ""
    @State var textField5 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                TextField("\(index)", text: $textField1)
            }
```

I'm trying to use item indexes to achieve my goal but don't know how.
I need each TextField to be bound to its own individual variable.

Comment: You need an array of strings. Ranges are considered unsafe with SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your `@State` an array:

```
@State var textFields = Array(repeating: "", count: 5)
```

and bind it to each text field:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
        TextField("\(index)", text: $textFields[index]) // <-- like this
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .font(.largeTitle)
    // ...
```

Comment: Safer to use `ForEach(textFields.indices)`

Comment: @AshleyMills well, that too is not ideal, as it's not a constant range... So it would need an overall better design, and I think it's beyond this question